# Chainlink - Not returning output for Chainlink.Request if passing a tokenized URL

Tags: solidity, remix, chainlink

I am using the APIConsumer https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/ contract but using my own API to get data. Its working if I am using open API(https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all) but its failing/not returning any value if using tokenized or user/password api

Please help

Comment: Can you please post your code, as well as which oracle and job you're using for the request (ie is it your node or a node from market.link)

Comment: I am using this code https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/ but just replacing the URL.

Comment: thanks, what jobID and oracle contract values are you using, and where did you get them from

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.